# How does we print the output in column

Tags: python

I have one problem in programming.The problem is that I have to give a input of one number and it will print all numbers from that number

Here if i give the input of 3 :
Then output will be 123

I wrote a sample code for this:

```
N=int(input())
for N in range(1,N+1):
    print(N)
```

It will give output as follows:

```
1
2
3
```

To want to give output column wise.So what changes I can do in program to get the output in column.

Comment: change `print(N)` with the `print(N , end=' ')`.

Comment: or `print(*range(1,int(input())+1))` - use `print(*range(1,int(input())+1), sep="")` if you really want no space between numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
for N in range(1, N + 1):
    print(N, end=' ')
```

the output is:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```